# Warning: Action does not match allowed action names pattern, cleaning it up

Tags: java, regex, struts2

I have below `struts.xml`:

```xml
<action name="viewreports" class="com.mypackage.action.ViewReportsAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="notauth" />
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result>/staff-view-reports.jsp</result>
    <result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="viewdepartment" class="com.mypackage.action.ViewDepartmentAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="notauth" />
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result>/staff-view-department.jsp</result>
    <result name="input" type="redirectAction">viewreports</result>
    <result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

It does what it should, but this warning shows up in the console:

```
WARNING: Action ["viewdepartment"] does not match allowed action names pattern [[a-zA-Z0-9._!/\-]*], cleaning it up!
```

Is there really something wrong with my action name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern doesn't allow double quotes in the action name. The action name and namespace are determined by the action mapper via parsing URI of the request. At this time a mapper is trying to set the action mapping to appropriate action name and namespace with the possibility of defaulting to `""`. And it uses the above pattern to match the action name when cleaning it up. You action name doesn't match that pattern, hence you get a warning. The xml configuration looks good.